# How to write Rewrite rule for full URL in web.config?

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

I want to write rewrite rule for full URL like

```
    <rule name="r1" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="abc.com/man/mostpopulararticles/brides.aspx" ignoreCase="true" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="abc.com/man.aspx" />
    </rule>
```

is it possible. I have tried but it didn't work for me. Is there any other way to do so. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
<rule name="r1" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^man/mostpopulararticles/brides.aspx$"/>
      <action type="Redirect" url="abc.com/man.aspx" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent"/>
 </rule>
```

It will be http:// and abc.com as it is not allowing me to enter the url.
Something like this works in my code.

Answer (score 0):

here is the code worked for me:

```
<rule name="Uk1" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^man/mostpopulararticles/brides.aspx" ignoreCase="true" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www.)?abc.co.uk$" />            
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="/man.aspx" />
    </rule>
```

Thanks All